# BigQuery - combine fragmented events

Tags: sql, database, group-by, google-bigquery, gaps-and-islands

Here is a sample data:

```
create table activity as
select "2020-02-25T09:06:12" as datetime_start,  "2020-02-25T09:07:31" as datetime_end, 0 as flag uniuon all 
select "2020-02-25T09:16:08" as datetime_start,  "2020-02-25T09:17:31" as datetime_end, 0 as flag uniuon all 
select "2020-02-25T09:17:31" as datetime_start,  "2020-02-25T09:27:31" as datetime_end, 1 as flag uniuon all 
select "2020-02-25T09:27:31" as datetime_start,  "2020-02-25T09:32:41" as datetime_end, 1 as flag uniuon all 
select "2020-02-25T09:35:57" as datetime_start,  "2020-02-25T09:37:31" as datetime_end, 0 as flag uniuon all 
select "2020-02-25T09:49:23" as datetime_start,  "2020-02-25T09:51:16" as datetime_end, 0 as flag uniuon all 
select "2020-02-25T09:51:16" as datetime_start,  "2020-02-25T10:03:46" as datetime_end, 1 as flag uniuon all 
select "2020-02-25T10:03:46" as datetime_start,  "2020-02-25T10:05:57" as datetime_end, 1 as flag uniuon all 
select "2020-02-25T10:05:57" as datetime_start,  "2020-02-25T10:07:31" as datetime_end, 1 as flag uniuon all 
select "2020-02-25T10:07:31" as datetime_start,  "2020-02-25T10:10:22" as datetime_end, 1 as flag uniuon all 
select "2020-02-25T10:10:22" as datetime_start,  "2020-02-25T10:12:55" as datetime_end, 1 as flag uniuon all 
select "2020-02-25T10:12:55" as datetime_start,  "2020-02-25T10:20:17" as datetime_end, 1 as flag uniuon all 
select "2020-02-25T10:20:17" as datetime_start,  "2020-02-25T10:27:40" as datetime_end, 1 as flag uniuon all 
select "2020-02-25T10:27:40" as datetime_start,  "2020-02-25T10:39:51" as datetime_end, 1 as flag;
```

I am looking for query that will compute the activity block based on the flag column.
If the flag is set to 1, than the rows after it till flag changes to 0 needs to be combined into a single activity block.

The above example results in 6 activity blocks.

1. 2020-02-25T09:06:12 - 2020-02-25T09:07:31
2. 2020-02-25T09:16:08 - 2020-02-25T09:17:31
3. 2020-02-25T09:17:31 - 2020-02-25T09:32:41
4. 2020-02-25T09:35:57 - 2020-02-25T09:37:31
5. 2020-02-25T09:49:23 - 2020-02-25T09:51:16
6. 2020-02-25T09:51:16 - 2020-02-25T10:39:51

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answers the original version of the question.

GMB's answer may work, but it seems to bespoke, because it hardcodes the value of the flag.  I prefer a more general approach:

```
with activity as (
    select "2020-02-25T09:06:12" as datetime_start,  "2020-02-25T09:07:31" as datetime_end, 0 as flag union all 
    select "2020-02-25T09:16:08" as datetime_start,  "2020-02-25T09:17:31" as datetime_end, 0 as flag union all 
    select "2020-02-25T09:17:31" as datetime_start,  "2020-02-25T09:27:31" as datetime_end, 1 as flag union all 
    select "2020-02-25T09:27:31" as datetime_start,  "2020-02-25T09:32:41" as datetime_end, 1 as flag union all 
    select "2020-02-25T09:35:57" as datetime_start,  "2020-02-25T09:37:31" as datetime_end, 0 as flag union all 
    select "2020-02-25T09:49:23" as datetime_start,  "2020-02-25T09:51:16" as datetime_end, 0 as flag union all 
    select "2020-02-25T09:51:16" as datetime_start,  "2020-02-25T10:03:46" as datetime_end, 1 as flag union all 
    select "2020-02-25T10:03:46" as datetime_start,  "2020-02-25T10:05:57" as datetime_end, 1 as flag union all 
    select "2020-02-25T10:05:57" as datetime_start,  "2020-02-25T10:07:31" as datetime_end, 1 as flag union all 
    select "2020-02-25T10:07:31" as datetime_start,  "2020-02-25T10:10:22" as datetime_end, 1 as flag union all 
    select "2020-02-25T10:10:22" as datetime_start,  "2020-02-25T10:12:55" as datetime_end, 1 as flag union all 
    select "2020-02-25T10:12:55" as datetime_start,  "2020-02-25T10:20:17" as datetime_end, 1 as flag union all 
    select "2020-02-25T10:20:17" as datetime_start,  "2020-02-25T10:27:40" as datetime_end, 1 as flag union all 
    select "2020-02-25T10:27:40" as datetime_start,  "2020-02-25T10:39:51" as datetime_end, 1 as flag
    )
select min(datetime_start) as datetime_stat,
       max(datetime_end) as datetime_end,
       flag
from (select a.*,
             countif( datetime_start <> prev_datetime_end OR
                      prev_flag <> flag
                    ) over (order by datetime_start) as grp
       from (select a.*,
                    lag(flag) over (order by datetime_start) as prev_flag,
                    lag(datetime_end) over (order by datetime_start) as prev_datetime_end
             from activity a
            ) a
) t
group by flag, grp
```

Comment: @ronencozen . . . No.  I don't look at modified questions if they invalidate answers.  The better approach is to ask a new question.

Comment: i see, thank you anyway for a nice answer to my original question.

Answer (score 2):

This is a gaps-and-islands variants. Here is an approach that uses `lag()` and and a window sum to define the groups of consecutive `1`s:

```
select
    min(datetime_start) datetime_stat,
    max(datetime_end) datetime_end,
    flag
from (
    select
        t.*,
        sum(case when flag = 1 and lag_flag = 1 then 0 else 1 end) 
            over(order by datetime_start) grp
    from (
        select 
            t.*,
            lag(flag) over(order by datetime_start) lag_flag
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
group by flag, grp
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.
I plug in your solution into my query, and it does not output what i am looking for.

Comment: Let's take as an example activity block number 3 which is composed for rows #3 & #4.  instead of combining it into a single row, I get in return to original rows with the datetime_end equal to the datetime_end of the prior row.

Comment: @ronencozen: [here is a db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hNr2h8hx7GF8n4Xq8xdoRU/0). This seems to produce the correct results for your sample data (that’s a MySQL fiddle since there is no BQ fiddle as far as I know, but the logic is the same, this is standard SQL).

Comment: here is a link to BigQuery sandbox.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/sandbox